# Как передать каждый элемент массива внутрь асинхронных функций и записать результат в файл?

Tags: javascript, async-await, map, tensorflow, promise

Элементы массива не заходят в асинхронные функции для получения embeddings.
в Консоли выдает только "START START START START" и т.д. Не могу понять почему, ведь мэппинг оформлен в Promise, которую мы потом возвращаем и записываем все результаты в файл. Идея такова что надо строчки, которые записаны через запятую для каждого юзера передать в функции TensorFlow и Universal Sentence Encoder, чтобы получить потом вектора для этого текста для каждого юзера и сохранить уже нового юзера с векторами в файл. Но проблема асинхронности не позволяет это сделать.
[Пример кода для функций энкодэра](https://github.com/jinglescode/demos/tree/master/src/app/components/nlp-sentence-encoder) Там конечно они работают исключительно с then() вместо async/await, но тогда я тем более не понимаю как каждый эдемент может пройти через функции внутри map.

```
const fillDocument = async () => {

  let model = await use.load()
  let dataWithVectors = await Promise.all(data.map(async user => {
    let sentences = "";
    sentences = user.biography + ","
    user.latestMedia.forEach(mediaitems => {
      if (mediaitems.caption) {
        sentences += mediaitems.caption + ","
      }
    })
    console.log("START")
    let embeddings = await model.embed([sentences]);
    console.log("EMBEDDINGS: ", embeddings);
    let arr = await embeddings.array();
    user.unit_vector = arr[0];
  }));
  return dataWithVectors
}
fillDocument().then(data => {
  fs.writeFile("./scraper/vectors.json", JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("JSON file has been saved.");
  });
})
```

Comment: Какой язык программирования? Добавьте тег с языком.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо! js добавлен!

Comment: А в консоли не выдается `EMBEDDINGS`? Если так, тогда вызов функции `await model.embed([sentences])` не резолвится или reject делает. Добавите после `fillDocument().then` еще `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем! Отвечаю на вопрос сама, если поможет кому-нибудь:

заменить Promise.all и map(() => {} на for (let user of data) {...}, который помог из асинхрона сделать синхрон, теперь каждый элемент из лупа ждет выполнение функций внутри loop.

```
  console.log("START")
  // let dataWithVectors = await Promise.all(data.map(async user => {
  for (let user of data) {
    let sentences = "";
    sentences = user.biography + ","
    for (mediaitem of user.latestMedia) {
      if (mediaitem.caption) {
        sentences += mediaitem.caption + ","
      }
    }
    console.log("next element: ", data.indexOf(user))
    let embeddings = await model.embed([sentences])
    console.log("EMBEDDINGS: ", embeddings);
    let arr = await embeddings.array();
    user.unit_vector = arr[0];
  };
  console.log("FINISHED")
```